# XSLT for XML to HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like this.

```
< cars>  
< car>  
< ford color="black" >eco sport< /ford >    
< maruti color="red" >zen< /maruti>  
< hyundai color="blue" >accent< /hyundai>  
< /car>  
< car>  
< ford color="green" >figo< /ford >    
< maruti color="red" >swift< /maruti>  
< hyundai color="white" >santro< /hyundai>  
< /car>  
< /cars>
```

I need to have an HTMl table like

```
COMPANY   COLOR    MODEL  
 ford     black   ecosport  
 maruti   red     zen    
 hyundai  green   figo  
 ford     red     swift  
 maruti   red     zen    
 hyundai  white   santro
```

Could anyone help me with this.. I am very new to XSLT and spent some valuble time for this but no luck. Thanks in advance. Below is the XSLT i have been trying with

```
<xsl:template match ="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Cars </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cars">
    <table width="400" border="1" >
        <tr bgcolor = "#cccccc" >
            <td>COMPANY</td>
            <td>COLOR</td>
            <td>MODEL</td>
        </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="car">
        <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>    
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="@color" /> </td>
                <td> <xsl:value-of select="ford" /> </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
     </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a few (small) problems with you XSLT. Firstly, this line is not valid

```
<xsl:for-each select="./">
```

What you need to be doing at this point, as you are positioned on a **car** element, is to iterate over each child element, like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
```

Second, you want to create the **tr** element within this loop, rather than outside as you are currently doing. Thirdly, to get the model, you are doing this

```
<xsl:value-of select="ford" />
```

When it should be just this

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> Cars </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cars">
        <table width="400" border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                <td>COMPANY</td>
                <td>COLOR</td>
                <td>MODEL</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="car">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@color"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML (with the whitespace in element names removed!), the following is output

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Cars </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="400" border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                <td>COMPANY</td>
                <td>COLOR</td>
                <td>MODEL</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ford</td>
                <td>black</td>
                <td>eco sport</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>maruti</td>
                <td>red</td>
                <td>zen</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hyundai</td>
                <td>blue</td>
                <td>accent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ford</td>
                <td>green</td>
                <td>figo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>maruti</td>
                <td>red</td>
                <td>swift</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hyundai</td>
                <td>white</td>
                <td>santro</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is absolutely working. One more question even though. Can i have an indent before 'zen' if element equals maruti?

Comment: So you want spacing to the left of the model name only for maruti zens?

Comment: yes.. so my condition should be like if 'maruti' then 2 spaces zen nad in next row if 'hyundai' then 3 spaces accent

Comment: Sounds like you could have some increasingly complicated logic there, that may warrant a whole new question. For example, what if 'hyundai' is the previous row, and not the next row? Are there, in fact, other cars you will need to indent too? You could possibly solve this in CSS though. Give you table cell a class attribute of the modal `<td class='{name()}'>` and style it accordingly.

Comment: Solved this like ..                                           <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="name()='maruti'"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:when> <xsl:when test="name()='hyundai'"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose>

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. Please give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match ="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Cars </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cars">
    <table width="400" border="1" >
      <tr bgcolor = "#cccccc" >
        <th>COMPANY</th>
        <th>COLOR</th>
        <th>MODEL</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="car/*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@color" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is absolutely working. One more question even though. Can i have an indent before 'zen' if element equals maruti?